# How to mock only one dependency of test class in spring

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito, spring-test

I have a class, which has a lot of dependencies.

```java
@Service
public class TestClass {

    @Inject
    private DependencyA dependencyA;

    @Inject
    private DependencyB dependencyB;

    @Inject
    private DependencyC dependencyC;
    // .
    // .    
    // .    
    // .
    @Inject
    private DependencyZ dependencyZ;

    public boolean testMethod() {
        try {
            dependencyA.methodA();
            dependencyB.methodB();
            dependencyC.methodC();
            dependencyD.methodD();
            return true;
        } catch (StaleObjectStateException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to mock one of the dependencies and throw `exception` to test the `catch block` of this class.

So following is my test, where I mock `dependencyB` and throw `StaleObjectStateException` when `dependencyB.methodB();` called.

```java
public class TestClassIT {

    @InjectMocks
    private TestClass testClass;

    @InjectMocks
    private CustomRuleEngine customRuleEngine;

    @Mock
    private DependencyB dependencyB;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(TestClass.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnSuccessRuleAfterCreate() throws Exception {
        setupRequestContextWithFullPermission();
        when(dependencyB.methodB(any())).thenThrow(new StaleObjectStateException("f", "f"));
        // and expect exception.
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't work because all other dependencies of `TestClass` are injected as a `null`. How to solve this?
As I mentioned this class has a lot of dependencies and I can't mock each. The requirement is just of mock `dependencyB.methodB();`

Comment: It is not the right place to test dependency existence! If you have frozen dependencies, just use constructor injection and test the input parameters against NULL there. This type of existence test just needed if the dependency modification allowed. But you can test the input parameter in the setter method as well against NULL.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the cases where property injection is hurting.

Change `TestClass` to use constructor injection. Then you can instantiate it in your test yourself and inject whatever you want.

Comment: Are there any alternatives !!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define all your dependencies as mocks, not just DependencyB, so Mockito can do the injection. Even if you do not mock their methods, this way, there won't be null fields in your TestClass.

```
@Mock
private DependencyA dependencyA;

@Mock
private DependencyB dependencyB;

@Mock
private DependencyC dependencyC;
```